# SQL Server 2014 Express and C# (System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources())

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, windows, instance

Before you say anything: I have done the searching. I have seen the countless posts on StackOverflow about connecting to a named instance of SQL Server Express via C#.

But this is just weird. Using my SQL Server browser in Visual Studio, I am able to see AND connect to the named instance of SQL Server Express. However when I try to programmatically create a connection string using the `GetDataSources()` method (which is working fine for me btw), I am unable to connect to the SQL Server.

I have verified the connection string output of the program with the connection string that Visual Studio uses to connect via the SQL Server Management Studio. I know I have TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled in the manager. And my Server Browser is indeed running as well (or I wouldn't be able to see my server under `GetDataSources()`)

So: does anybody have any ideas as to why (when the connection string is the same) my program cannot connect to my instance of SQL Server 2014 Express? But Visual Studio can. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers y'all!

**EDIT** I have included my code to generate a connection string:

```
private void ConnectToServer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if(serverView.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(string.Format(
                @"Server={0}/{1};", (Environment.MachineName == SQLManager.servers.Rows[serverView.SelectedIndex]["ServerName"].ToString()) ? "(local)" :
                SQLManager.servers.Rows[serverView.SelectedIndex]["ServerName"].ToString(),
                SQLManager.servers.Rows[serverView.SelectedIndex]["InstanceName"].ToString())
                );
            builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            bool success = false;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SQLManager.conString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(builder.ConnectionString);
                    CreateDatabseIfNotExist();
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(builder.ConnectionString, "Connection Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                }
            }
}
```

As of now the connection string output (for Visual Studio) is:

```
Data Source=VIRTUAL-DEV-PC\MSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

My generated connection string (on the local machine where server is running):

```
Data Source=(local)\MSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=True
```

NOTE: I have also tried replacing `(local)` with `<VIRTUAL-DEV-PC>` <= machine name

Comment: Post your `connection string` and `code` which you have tried.

Comment: @AjayPunekar I have edit the original post to include more information and the source code.

Comment: I am just curious,  Why do you have this line after opening up the connection?
SQLManager.conString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(builder.ConnectionString);

And are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara I'm setting another SQL connection there. Basically: if I successfully connect to the server, then I set the connection string on my static SQLManager class to that string for use throughout the program life.